# Evaluating a matrix-vector product with the CKKS scheme

Tags: python, encryption, public-key-encryption, seal, homomorphic-encryption

For a simple project, I want to use the CKKS encryption scheme via the PYfhel library. I need to evaluate a matrix-vector product, e.g. Y = A*X.

**Question**: How to do it properly with PyFhel ?

**Partial Answers**

1. For the moment, my idea is to encrypt each coefficient of A and X as different data and implement the matrix vector product by writing manually the scalar product. But this solution is not really satisfactory and scalable. And I have doubt about the security of encrypting only scalars ?
2. I can implement the dot product of the first line of A with X and the second line of A with X. This will give me the two components of Y but how to get the fully encrypted vector ?